# How to properly use checkpoint to cache results from asynchronous web requests in Python?

Tags: python, caching, asynchronous, python-requests, pickle

I would like to use [ediblepickle checkpoint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ediblepickle/1.1.3) to cache the results from parsing a list of URLs with asynchronous http requests [request-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) module.

I want to create a checkpoint to cache the results from each individual URL (ie. one cache file per URL), so that I don't need to request and parse the same webpage again. However I am confused on how that would be implemented when I am using [request-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) to handle the HTTP requests.

**Implementation 1:**
I think it doesn't make sense to wrap a checkpoint cache around this whole function, because if one URL in `link_list` input changes, my cached results would be useless.

```
def get_all_captions(link_list):
    # Request/parse different pages (contained in link_list) within base_url website asynchoronously
    base_url = r'***BASE URL OF WEBSITE****'
    if s is None:
        s = FuturesSession()
    future = []

    ## make async request to different pages
    for link, _ in link_list:
        future.append(s.get(base_url + link))

    ## wait for results and parse
    caption_list = []
    for i in range(len(link_list)):
        r = future[i].result().text
        ####
        #### code to parse webpage context for some photo captions and store in caption_list
        ####
    return caption_list
```

**Implementation 2:**
If I create a sub-function like `get_captions_from_one_page()` below, then the whole process become synchronous and defeated the purpose.

```
def get_all_captions(link_list):
    base_url = r'***BASE URL OF WEBSITE ***'
    if s is None:
        s = FuturesSession()
    caption_list = []
    caption_list += get_captions_from_one_page(base_url + link, s)
    return caption_list

@checkpoint(key=lambda args,kargs: urllib2.quote(args[0].split('/')[-1])+'.p', work_dir=cache_dir, refresh=False)
def get_captions_from_one_page(link, s):
    future.append(s.get(link))
    r = future.result().text
    ### code to parse results and return caption_list for this page
    return caption_list
```

What is the proper way to use checkpoint with request-futures to cache the results of each single webpage? Thanks!